# How to stop task in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I ran a script in Oracle sql developer last night which is a quite simple command:
'update TABLE set column A=...'
The table is a large one maybe about 70GB.
The task kept running for the whole night and still running....
Could I just click on the stop button on the window? I'm afraid of locking the session or the rolling back procedure will take longer time.

So what will happen to the database after we click stop? Or is there a more efficient way to kill task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not to stop it from SQL Developer instead you can get the session id from [V$SESSION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223) of this connection and kill it

```
alter system kill session 'sid,serial#';
```